# Expectation of function under bounded cdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $F(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function such that $F(x)\geq G(x)$ for all $x$ for some function $G(x)$. If furthermore for some bounded, continuous function $h$
$$
\int \int \int_A h(x,y,z)dG(x)dG(y)dG(z)<\infty,
$$
does it then also hold that
$$
\int \int \int_A h(x,y,z)dF(x)dF(y)dF(z)<\infty?
$$

Comment: Sorry, this was confusing indeed, I now rephrased the question.

Comment: No, "inverse" is still in the title and still unclear.

Comment: If $h$ is bounded then automatically both integrals take some value in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: That depends on the area $A$ right? If $A=[0,\infty)^3$ for example, the integrals do not necessarily have to be finite.

Comment: If $|h(x,y,z)|\leq c\in\mathbb R$ on $\mathbb R^3$ then $\int_Ah(x,y,z)dF(x)dF(y)dF(z)\leq\int|h(x,y,z)|dF(x)dF(y)dF(z)\leq\int cdF(x)dF(y)dF(z)=c$